# Computer architecture - How to find the addresses in a block

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

A cache memory with 4 KiB, each block is 16 words, there are 64 lines in the cache.

Tag = 18

Index = 6

Block offset = 4

Byte Offset = 2

I want to know for block number 448 what is the first address in the block and what is the last address in the block.

I know that in the block there are 16 words, but I don't understand how I can find the last and first addresses.

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have seen that there are questions about computer architecture in stackoverflow, as well there is a tag that exist for that matter, therefore I strongly believe my question is not off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration a memory block is made of 16 words. Let me also assume that a word is 4 bytes and the memory is byte addressable.

1 Block = 16 words = 64 bytes

Block numbers usually grow with memory addresses, that is:

```
 Block       Address Range
Block #0        [0, 63]
Block #1        [64, 127]
Block #2        [128, 191]
  ...              ...
Block #448      [28672, 28735]
  ...              ...
```

In general, for a block *i* its address range is `[64*i, 64*i-1]`.